# sprintf to a list of char pointers in c? Segmentations errors

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, printf, arrays

I have this code that works (it's a bit stripped down):

```
char *parmList[6];

parmList[0] ="/root/ssl_send";
parmList[1] ="-m 1";            
...etc...
parmList[5] = NULL;
execvp(parmList[0], parmList);
```

Now I want to write something to one string in this list with sprintf (it's more correct to say that I want that one pointer of *parmList[6] points to a char array constructed with sprintf). I am getting "Segmentation errors" all the time.
I have tried:

- using malloc,
- declaring a double array so the memory space is reserved,
- using snprintf,....

I am obviously doing something wrong. The problem is similliar to [Sprintf Segmentation Fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184227/sprintf-segmentation-fault), just that I need to have a list of pointers/char_arrays for execvp.

Comment: Why don't you **show** us what you've tried instead of telling?

Comment: Most likely you are trying to modify a string literal through the pointer causing an Undefined Behavior and the crash.

Comment: String literals are typically read-only and it's UB to try and write to them. If you want to modify these then you need to allocate memory for them and copy the string literal data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that uses sprintf to create a string and uses that string in your argument list. Make sure you allocate enough space for the sprintf output.

```
char *parmList[6];
parmList[0] = "/bin/ls";
char arg1[10];
sprintf(arg1, "%s", "-l");
parmList[1] = arg1;
parmList[2] = NULL;
execvp(parmList[0], parmList);
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't read the question carefully enough the first time. Sample code updated.